# npm postinstall script - execute script from dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

sadly I can't find anything on this issue except for some stuff from 4 years ago.

Suppose I have 2 packages: `@my/package` and `@my/parent`.

Now in `@my/parent` I'm trying to use a postinstall script like this:
`postinstall: "node ./node_modules/@my/package/dist/postinstall.js"`

This will always fail though, because apparently at the time that the postinstall script is being called, the script file is not present.

Is it supposed to be like that? Aren't you able to call scripts from dependencies in postinstall?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Okay to answer my own question:

It is not recommended to use `./node_modules/@my/package/...` from within the postinstall script of `@my/parent` because depending on the consumers `package.json`/versions, `@my/package` might not be installed inside of `@my/parent` but as siblings. In this case the path won't resolve.

So if you want to use something from another package in your postinstall script, you'll have to rely on nodes module resolution. One way of doing this would be:
Instead of

```
postinstall: "node ./node_modules/@my/package/dist/postinstall.js"
```

do

```
postinstall: "node -r @my/package/dist/postinstall.js"
```